# Commutation relation for a rotated vector operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, vectors, commutator

It is well known that a set of operators $(V_x,V_y,V_z)$ is called a vector operator if, given the total angular momentum $(J_x,J_y,J_z)$ of a system, it satisfies the following commutation relations
\begin{equation}
\left[V_a,J_b\right]=i\epsilon_{abc}V_c
\end{equation}
Let us assume now that we consider a new set of operators obtained by applying a rotation to $\vec{V}$
\begin{equation}
V'_{a}=\sum_b R_{ab}V_b
\end{equation}
where $R$ is the corresponding rotation matrix (equivalently one could use the unitary transformation associated to $R$).
My qustion is, can we show that the $\vec{V}'$ is again a vector operator? That is, does the commutation relation
\begin{equation}
\left[V'_a,J_b\right]=i\epsilon_{abc}V'_c
\end{equation}
hold?
To my intuition it should, but i haven't found an easy way to show that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficulty with the way you have formulated your question is that, on the one hand, you have an infinitesimal relation in the form of a commutator, while on the other hand you have a finite rotation of your operators.  The solution is to either "go finite" or "go infinitesimal" all the way.

If you "go finite", note first that your definition of a vector operator
is equivalent to 
$$
R(\omega)V_mR^{-1}(\omega)=\sum_k V_kD^1_{km}(\omega)\, ,
$$
where $R(\omega)$ is a rotation operator and $D^1_{km}(\omega)$ a rotation matrix.  In its most intuitive form
$$
R(\omega)= \exp\left(-i \vec{\omega} \cdot {\vec J} \right)
$$
and you can recover
$$
[V_m,J_b]=i\frac{\partial}{\partial \omega_b} R(\omega)V_m R^{-1}(\omega)\Bigl\vert_{\vec{\omega} =0}\, .\tag{1}
$$
In this way you can then verify that $V'_a=R(\Omega)V_aR^{-1}(\Omega)$ transforms properly because
\begin{align}
R(\omega) V_a'R^{-1}(\omega)&= R(\omega)R(\Omega)V_aR^{-1}(\Omega)R^{-1}(\omega)\, ,\\
&=R(\omega\circ\Omega)V_a R^{-1}(\omega\circ\Omega)\, ,\\
&=\sum_k V_k D^1_{ka}(\omega\circ\Omega)\, ,\\
&=\sum_k V_k \left[\sum_m D^1_{km}(\omega)D^1_{ma}(\Omega)\right]. \tag{2}
\end{align}
as it should.  Here, $R(\omega\circ\Omega)=R(\omega)R(\Omega)$ is the product of rotatons; since rotations form a group it a rotation parametrized by three angles denoted as $\omega\circ\Omega$ since the rotation parameters $\omega$ and $\Omega$ are not additive (rotations are not Abelian).  Alternatively, you can multiply the $D$'s in (2) and use this to infer the angles $\omega\circ\Omega$.  Either way you can then recover the commutator version using (1).

Alternatively, you can start with $V'_a$ just an infinitesimal rotation away from $V_a$ and work entirely with commutators.